# Convert NSManaged Object to array iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am using JSQCoreDataKit(https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQCoreDataKit) to fetch data from Coredata

So when I fetch, it returns result.objects of type AnyObject

How can I convert it into a array of objects so that I can access the properties like id and name.

```
internal static func GetCountryEntityList(entityname: String, predicate: String)->AnyObject{
    let model = CoreDataModel(name: module, bundle: NSBundle(identifier: bundle)!)

    let stack = CoreDataStack(model: model)

    let privateStack = CoreDataStack(model: model, storeType: NSInMemoryStoreType, options: nil, concurrencyType: .PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)

    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)

    let countryEntity = entity(name: entityname, context: stack.managedObjectContext)
    let request = FetchRequest<Country>(entity: countryEntity)
    if predicate != ""{
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: predicate)
        request.predicate = predicate
    }
    request.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    let result = fetch(request: request, inContext: stack.managedObjectContext)

    if !result.success {
        println("Error = \(result.error)")
    }

    return result.objects
}
```

This is the code for getting data from CoreData using JSQCoreData

```
    var countryListNew = [Country]()
    countryListNew = CoreDataManager.GetCountryEntityList("Country", predicate: "") as! [Country]
```

Above is the code in my Controller

[image]

This is what result.objects is

[image]

This is what countryListNew is

See I am not able to access name or id

[image]
Country class

Comment: Have you tried adding ```as! {yourObject}``` when you are accessing the object?

Comment: Yes countryListNew = CoreDataManager.GetCountryEntityList("Country", predicate: "") as! [(Country)] but when i try countryListNew[0].name then its error

Comment: when I checked countryListNew there is 251 elements, but when I try countryListNew[0].id it says Array index out of range

Comment: please share the code you have written so far. It would be far easier to help you that way.

Comment: Well, as long as result.objects is correct, the countryListNew should be correct. I tried a similar code online and it works. Check it out:
http://swiftstub.com/370662823/

Comment: @harsh.prasad I tried your code, it is working  fine, but can you check my updated screenshots from xcode.

Comment: You are accessing name on countryList instead of countryListNew. Isn't that a problem?

Comment: Sorry about that, I was playing around, but I tried with countryListNew[0].name its the same result

Comment: Hmm.. Thought so. There could be some problem with the casting then. Can you share how does Country class look like.

Comment: @harsh.prasad updated with Country class, Its generated from CoreData, I added the necessary code for JSQCoreDataKit

Comment: Ok. The problem seems to be lying somewhere in results.object. Try looping on results.object and then casting individual elements. Debug during this loop to see what the object looks like.

Comment: I am not even getting countryListNew[0].name but I am getting result.objects[0].name, So even if I tried to loop countryListNew, I am not getting country name or id